# using Xsl variable

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem accessing variable in XSLT.
I just define var like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="myName" select="@owner"/>
```

When I use this code it does not work:

```
<title>{$myName}</title>
```

but with this code works:

```
<title><xsl:value-of select="$myName"/></title>
```

I want to compare the variable above with each **from** entity in XML
when value of **from** entity equal **myName** I display some code otherwise another code display

```
<xsl:for-each select="message">
   <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="from = $myName">
           ...
      </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            ...
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XML file contains this information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="history.xsl"?>
<history xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="history.xsd" owner="Mike">

 <message>
    <from>Mike</from>
    <to>Gem</to>
    <date>2002-09-24</date>
    <color>red</color>
    <size>20</size>
    <family>cursive</family>
    <style>overline</style>
    <body>welcome</body>
 </message>
</history>
```

Comment: You need to provide relevant XML input and desired XML output so we can better workout the problem. Looks like you want `test="@from = $myName"` (mind the "@")

Comment: Where is the "owner" attribute you refer to in the variable ?

Comment: Are you trying this : http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsD ?

Comment: yes but i take **myName** from **owner** attribute in first tag **history**

Comment: See the answer, think I got what you wanted !

Comment: yes this solve my problem .. many thanks to you

Comment: Note that the syntax `<title>{$myName}</title>` is actually known as a "text value template" and is only available in XSLT 3.0 (See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates). In XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0, you can only have Attribute Value Templates, so the syntax is only available in attributes. For example `<title name="{$myName}" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="myName" select="/history/@owner"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message">
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="from = $myName">
           Mike message
      </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Other message
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>        
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

It will pull the value at the start of execution and put it in the "myName" variable.

Then, I match on tag name (message) and use the XSL choose as you did.

You can also avoid using the xsl:choose by doing so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="myName" select="/history/@owner"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message[from=$myName]">        
           Mike message                  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message">        
           Other message                  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This shows you something important : XSL pick the first matching template !

The second option is better suited for modularity. The first one imply nesting. This second do not !

Test both online:

- http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsD/4
- http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsD/2